# Yes or No in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, scripting

I have a set of 100 questions. My requirement is when a user enter "yes", then question 1 should appear. If not, directly it go to question 2. Like that it should go on till 100 questions. Any lead would be appreciated.

This is what I tried, but it is failing.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Execute question1 "
select result in Yes No
do
    echo "How to see apache config file"
    exit
done
echo "execute question2"
select result in Yes No Cancel
do
    echo "Command for listing processes"
    exit
done
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Is it always has to show question 1 on "Yes"? or it is like, it should iterate from 1 to 100 and in case user enters Yes, it should print that particular question or else it should just move to next question?

Comment: That's right. If the user enter yes for question1, it should print that question and move to next. If he enters NO for question 1, it should directly go for question2

Comment: Also, where are you maintaining the list of 100 questions?

Comment: Planned to write it on the script itself. Sorry I am new to this. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do this with an array.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

questions=(
   "How to see apache config file"
   "Command for listing processes"
   "My hovercraft is full of eels"
)

for((q=0; q<${#questions[@]}; q++)); do
    echo "Execute question $q?"
    select result in Yes No; do
        case $result in
         Yes)
            echo "${questions[q]}";;
        esac
        break
    done
done
```

Using `select` for this seems rather clumsy, though. Perhaps just replace it with

```sh
    read -p "Execute question $q? " -r result
    case $result in
        [Yy]*) echo "${questions[q]}";;
    esac
```

Having just a list of questions still seems weird. With Bash 5+ you could have an associative array, or you could have a parallel array with the same indices with answers to the questions.  But keeping each question and answer pair together in the source would make the most sense.  Maybe loop over questions and answers and assign every other one to an `answers` array, and only increment the index when you have read a pair?

```sh
pairs=(
    "How to see Apache config file"
    "cat /etc/httpd.conf"

    "Command for listing processes"
    "ps"

    "My hovercraft is full of what?"
    "eels"
)

questions=()
answers=()
for((i=0; i<=${#pairs[@]}/2; ++i)); do
    questions+=("${pairs[i*2]}")
    answers+=("${pairs[1+i*2]}")
done
```

This ends up with two copies of everything, so if you are really strapped for memory, maybe refactor to just a `for` loop over the strings and get rid of the `pairs` array which is only useful during initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of questions and loop over it, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1
questions=(
    'How to see apache config file'
    'Command for listing processes'
)

check_user_input(){
    read -p "y/n " input
    case $input in
         [Yy]*) return 0;;
         [Nn]*) return 1;;
             *) check_user_input;;
    esac
}

for question in "${questions[@]}"; {
      echo "Execute question $n"
      check_user_input && echo "$question"
      ((n++))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ***straight forward*** example. Play with it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type 'y' for yes, 'n' to skip or 'q' to quit and press Enter!"
for((i=1; i < 101; ++i)); do
    echo 'Execute question '$i
    while read user_input; do
        if [[ "$user_input" = 'q' ]]; then
            break 2
        elif [[ "$user_input" = 'n' ]]; then
            break
        elif [[ $i -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo 'How to see apache config file?'
            break 2 # Change from "break 2" to  "break" for the next question.
        elif [[ $i -eq 2 ]]; then
            echo 'Command for listing processes.'
            break 2 # Change from "break 2" to "break" for the next question.
        else
            echo "Wrong input: $user_input"
            echo "Type 'y' for yes, 'n' to skip or 'q' to quit and press Enter!"
        fi
    done
done

echo 'Finished'
```

Comment: The big `if / elif / elif ... ` statement looks like it wants to be desperately refactored into a `case` statement.

Comment: @triplee Hahha.. Yes. I'm just making it straight forward here. OP probably want to use `break` instead of `break 2` for the last 2 `elif`'s to progress though. I'll leave it as an execise for the OP.